# Redirecting non-www to www without redirecting cdn

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I need to write an .htaccess redirection rule that will permanently redirect requests for:

`example.com` to  `www.example.com`

and

`example.com/stuff/anyfile.ext`  to  `www.example.com/stuff/anyfile.ext`

but **without** redirecting other forms, like

`cdn.example.com`  or  `cdn.example.com/stuff/anyfile.ext` to `www.example.com`

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

... but it **doesn't** work with links to images.  So that:

`example.com/stuff/my-image.jpg`

does **not** get redirected to:

`www.example.com/stuff/my-image.jpg`

Is it impossible?

full .htaccess link:
http://pastebin.com/wCmE9zDw

Comment: You said you did **not** want to redirect images to `www` so my answer should work for you.

Comment: No I didn't. I said I just wanted to exclude requests for `cdn.example.com`.  I was saying that my example rule works **except for** image links.

Comment: Read my answer, That's what it sound like you said. that if it was example.com/stuff/file.jpg then do not redirect to www version.

Comment: My apologies for not being clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your condition slightly. Have it check just for the domain instead of the absence of `www`. See if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can use your domain specifically as well in the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Then simply remove that condition as I updated it. Make sure to clear cache or try in another browser. If this is the first rule in the .htaccess, it should redirect everything as it's the first rule. What happens if it's an image.

Comment: The results are the same as I described to anubhava - everything works as expected in a test non-WP domain, but in a WP domain, if the link is to an image, it will not redirect the request from non-www to www.  It's the first thing written in the root .htaccess, the rest of which is open to inspection (link above) so this is puzzling.

Comment: Have you check your wp-config file? maybe it's causing an issue `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');`
`define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` It seems to be related to WP. see if the config has www.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you.  That works except it does not redirect image links. I cleared my browser cache.

Comment: After further testing I can see that it does work with image links on another domain - it must be something else further down in my .htaccess file on the first domain that is conflicting with it.

Comment: If you edit link below your question and provide your .htaccess then I can probably suggest something.

Comment: I added a link to the full .htaccess file - perhaps you can see what's preventing your code from working.

Comment: Looked at your htaccess. Looks fine to me. Are you seeing `cdn.example.com` becoming `www.cdn.example.com` in browser? If not then I suspect some WP plugin conflict here. As you've also noticed that this rule works fine otherwise.

Comment: No, `cdn.example.com` stays `cdn.example.com`

Comment: The only 'error' that remains is that it won't redirect links (from non-www to www) when the links are links to images - eg a link to `example.com/image.jpg` doesn't become redirected to `www.example.com/image.jpg `.  It's puzzling because that does work OK on a non-WP domain, but not on a WP domain (despite your not being able to see anything likely to be conflicting in the ret of the .htaccess file).

Comment: Test this in Chrome dev tool. Visit `http://example.com/image.jpg` and see if you get any redirects or not. It is likely those WP cache plugins are returning image from some cache.